# A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: c#, xamarin.uwp

I'm working on an UWP application (Universal Windows) and I got this problem, I'm hoping that your talent will help me a lot. The problem is I plugged an headset HidDevice to read Firmware Version from that headset.

Here is my code:

```
public async void ReadFirmwareVersion()
    {
        if (DeviceManagerEventHandler.Current.HidDevice != null)
        {
            HidOutputReport outReport = DeviceManagerEventHandler.Current.HidDevice.CreateOutputReport();
            byte[] buffer = queryVersion();
            DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter();
            dataWriter.WriteBytes(buffer);

            outReport.Data = dataWriter.DetachBuffer();

            await DeviceManagerEventHandler.Current.HidDevice.SendOutputReportAsync(outReport);

            HidInputReport inReport = await DeviceManagerEventHandler.Current.HidDevice.GetInputReportAsync();

            if (inReport != null)
            {
                UInt16 id = inReport.Id;
                var bytes = new byte[64];
                DataReader dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(inReport.Data);
                dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
            }
            else
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser("Invalid input report received", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Byte[] queryVersion()
    {
        Byte[] cmd = new Byte[64];
        cmd[0] = 0x0B;
        cmd[1] = 0x11;
        return cmd;
    }
```

I got an error at 
**outReport.Data = dataWriter.DetachBuffer();** 
they said 
[Value does not fall within the expected range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewSz6.png) 
and 1 more error at  **HidInputReport inReport = await DeviceManagerEventHandler.Current.HidDevice.GetInputReportAsync();** is 
[A device attached to the system is not functioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY0gM.png)

I tried to get the headset firmware version but it didn't work out due to these errors. Please help, I spent 2 days almost. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: where did you get that magic number 64 from? IMO `IBuffer` size should [not be larger than actual number of bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.hidoutputreport) to transmit. don't know if that is related to the errors you get though.

Comment: @dlatikay I decreased the size of buffer to 2 or 4 but still got the problem. :(

Comment: try removing that roundtrip with the datawriter, [try this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9373c79-ae18-4716-b63e-7e87143c541f/how-to-convert-byte-to-windowsstoragestreamsibuffer?forum=winappswithcsharp): `outReport.Data = new byte[] { 0x0B, 0x11 }.AsBuffer();`